# Remainder in long division of a high degree polynomial by a quadratic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Find the remainder when $$ x^{2008} + 2008x + 2008 $$ is divided by
$$ x^2-3x+2.$$

I tried equating the divisor to 0, and used some polynomial reduction,  but couldn't get to a proper solution.
Here's what I did:
$$ x^{2008} + 2008x + 2008 = (x-1)(x-2)Q(x) + ax+b $$
I substituted $ x=1, 2 $
And solved for a and b, I got
$$a= 2^{2008}+2007, b = 2010-2^{2008}$$
What should I do next?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the remainder must have the form $Ax+B$.  Write down the defining equation for the remainder and try evaluating at useful values (like the roots of the quadratic).

Comment: You got the values of $a$ and $b$, so your answer is just $ax+b$. That's the remainder. If you are sure that $a,b$ are correct you can self-answer your question.

Comment: $ax+b$ with your values is the solution.

Comment: The answer of this question on the official site is 1. But my answer is coming out to be different

Comment: Then you may have calculated $a$ and $b$ wrong. Let me check. NO, the calculations you made are in fact CORRECT. So I'm surprised by the online solution. It's definitely wrong. Where's the official site?

Comment: @ShivamVishwekar Q 11 SMO 2008 Junior, asks for the remainder when $x^{2008}+2008x+2008$ is divided by $x+1$. Please see [here](https://fadjarp3g.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/2008-smo.pdf). The answer to that is just $1 -2008+2008 = 1$, which is what you seem to say.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Oh, Yes! U r right.

Comment: @ShivamVishwekar It is your choice whether you delete this post (despite of the given answer) or not. The calculation is useful for similar such exercises, but the actual exercise was utterly different (and in fact much easier).

Comment: Since the answer is already worked out, it makes sense anyway to close the post. Additional answers would not add anything useful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is worked out already.

Comment: @Peter ohk, pls close it, as I cannot since I am below 50 rep

Comment: I have only one close-vote, but we need only one more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(x)=x^{2008}+2008x+2008=Q(x)(x^2-3x+2)+ax+b =Q(x)(x-2)(x-1)+ax+b $$

$$P(1)=4017=a+b$$

$$P(2)=2^{2008}+6024=2a+b$$

$$a=2^{2008}+2007, b =2010-2^{2008}$$

$$R(x)=(2^{2008}+2007)x+2010-2^{2008}$$